# Power BI Real Time Scenario from Client

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I want to my whole report to show data on latest month once data get's added. How to do in Power BI?

I tried at report level filter, Also I am expecting whether it can do from DAX

Comment: A relative time slicer would be a goo use case, to always defaulting to the last month

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to limit the data displayed in your report to the latest month.

- First, create a calculated column that extracts the month from the
  date column in your data.
- Next, add a filter to your report and choose the option to "filter by a relative date".
- Set the filter to only show data where the month equals the maximum month extracted in step 1.
- Once you have set the filter, your report will automatically show data for the latest month as new data is added to your dataset.
- To refresh the report, you can right click on the report and select the refresh button

It's basic method you can use to filter by latest month